# What happens if you don't boycott all israeli products?

Tags: halal-haram, sin, jannah, jahannam

I try to boycott most of the products that support israel but not all, am i sinful for not boycotting and what kind of haram is it, do i take the rights of the palestinian people?

Comment: Why should it be haram and why do you take the rights of Palestinian people?Everybody should be responsible for himself "...Indeed, Allah will not change the condition of a people until they change what is in themselves. .." [13:11](https://legacy.quran.com/13/11) instead of working hard for their independence as most other countries and building a state they rely on money they spent to pay Israel with to get almost anything they need: electricity, gas, water, all kinds of goods ... This system is good for Israel: anything destroyed in Gaza will be rebuilt by Muslim Money and Israeli products.

Comment: The leaders of Hamas themselves call the people of Gaza as a responsibility of the UN while they were elected by them. They expect all Muslims to fight for them. ... this is what I'd call hypocrisy and betrayal of the own people. At the same time they are staying in air-conditioned luxury suites in Qatar and their children study at expensive universities abroad. And they call people to war, Jihad and whatever in many Muslim countries and while they let their people down.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I'd recommend editing this Q and make it much more abstract: Are we to boycott forms of consumption that might support a kafir harbi state? Are we sinful otherwise?

Comment: I asked because if i for example buy a product that supports israel and then they get the money, and later they might buy wepons with that money and kill innocent people.

Comment: Point is understood, at the end, your intention counts. But be aware that you may also harm Palestinians because they have no industry on white paper they are a state with a high GDP, however, they are dependent on Israel and donations since they have no real production so the money seemingly reaches the wrong people as usual. Please consider the above suggestion made by @Ir0.

Comment: So what should I do, is it haram?